# Python - recursive loop within a dict

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

Is there a cool way to traverse the dict recursively to get all the combination of the sum(values):

I have a dict `{a: 10, b: 20, c:30}`

I want to find all the unique combinations of twos and threes (Sum of the Values):

e.g. twos

```
30  # 10 + 20
40  # 10 + 30
50  # 20 + 30
```

similarly for threes:

```
60 # 10 + 20 + 30
```

Comment: What do you mean by "recursively"? Do you mean that the solution must involve recursive programming, or that it must support dicts that themselves contain other dicts?

Comment: Wanted to traverse the same dict to sum the combination of the values.  E.g. Something that I would have done in a using a for loop :  (For i in range (0,2): for j in range (i,2))

Comment: @userDSSR, my answer uses loops that create a powerset of all combinations up to the len of the dict values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `itertools` as follows:

```
import itertools
mydict = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c':30}
result = [mydict[x] + mydict[y] for x, y in itertools.combinations(d, 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Liked the way to get keys and values.

Comment: @userDSSR, this does not even answer your question

Comment: It worked.  I just had to change itertools.combinations(d,3) to get the combination for 3's.  result = [mydict[x] + mydict[y]  + mydict[z] for x, y, z in itertools.combinations(d, 3)]

Comment: @userDSSR, "I want to find all the unique combinations of twos and threes" "and" being the operative word.

Answer (score 3):

For the example input you have given, you can use a combination of `map`, `sum`, and `itertools.combinations`:

```
d = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c':30}

import itertools
print map(sum, itertools.combinations(d.values(), 2))
print map(sum, itertools.combinations(d.values(), 3))
```

Or, in Python3:

```
d = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c':30}

import itertools
print(list(map(sum, itertools.combinations(d.values(), 2))))
print(list(map(sum, itertools.combinations(d.values(), 3))))
```

prints:

```
[40, 30, 50]
[60]
```

Comment: This probably works fine.  I got an error.. <map object at 0x00B9EF30> <map object at 0x00B9EF30> for the above statements.  I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: That's funny, you *should* get a syntax error in Python 3.4. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to get all the combinations and then sum the results.

E.g.

```
from itertools import combinations

mydict = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c':30}
twos = [sum(c) for c in combinations(mydict.values(), 2)]
threes = [sum(c) for c in combinations(mydict.values(), 3)]
print twos
print threes
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: the solutions using `combinations` above are better!
But I'll keep this anyway.

```
from itertools import permutations
data = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c':30}

for key_perm in permutations(data.keys(), 2):
  print ' + '.join(key_perm), '=', sum(data[k] for k in key_perm)
```

Prints:

```
a + c = 40
a + b = 30
c + a = 40
c + b = 50
b + a = 30
b + c = 50
```

But probably you want only distinct sums, since addition of integers is commutative. Sets come to the rescue.

```
for key_perm in set(tuple(sorted(perm)) for perm in permutations(data.keys(), 2)):
  print ' + '.join(key_perm), '=', sum(data[k] for k in key_perm)
```

Prints:

```
b + c = 50
a + b = 30
a + c = 40
```

The use of `tuple` above is needed because `set()` only takes immutable items, and `sorted()` returns a mutable `list`.

Comment: this does not add 10 + 20 + 30

Answer (score 0):

Power set:

```
d={'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c':30}
def power_set(items):
    n = len(items)
    for i in xrange(2**n):
        combo = []
        for j in xrange(n):
            if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:
                combo.append(items[j])
        yield combo
data= [sum(x) for x in  list(power_set(d.values())) if len(x)>1]
In [10]: data
Out[10]: [40, 30, 50, 60]
```